# Component constructor inside ng-content not called

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular 8 project I have parent component that has ng-content with *ngIf. For some reason any child component inside ng-content created only once. Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x1seyb)  example where I hide content and then redisplay it. Click button and in console you can see that either constructor or onInit called only once the first time things rendered.

Is it bug? If not how can I force my content to recreate? Btw if I do `<div>` instead of `<ng-content>` then all is working fine.

**Edit**: I just updated stackblitz with new suggestion. Still not working :(

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the `<ng-content>` inside a template, and then conditionally render the template. I'm not sure of the reason why, but it seems that Angular will only resolve inner content once.

When a template is rendered Angular will resolve `<ng-content>`, because the view for the template is recreated.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="condition">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentRef"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #contentRef">
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I just updated stackblitz but its still not working. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can acces to your testComponent using ContentChild, then you can call to any method of the testComponent. As supouse you want to has differents "test-component", only remember give a template reference variable to your component(*)

```
<app-cont>
    <app-test #test></app-test>
</app-cont>
```

Your count-component

```
 @ContentChild('test',{static:false}) test:any

  reload() {
    this.show = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.show = true;
      this.test.ngOnInit()
    }, 1000);
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xwsnkn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcont%2Fcont.component.ts)

(*) the ContentChild also admit a syntax like

```
@ContentChild(TestComponent,{static:false}) text:TestComponent
```

but this only find it if the content is a TestComponent

Comment: The goal is to trigger constructor of the child component every time ngIf is false in the parent's ng-content